# Solving a non linear 2nd order ODE with python

Tags: python, scipy, sympy, ode

I'm looking for a solution to:

```
Dy'' + (y)**2 + psi*y*y'- (M(y')**2)/y = 0,
```

with `psi = x / t`,  `u(x, t)= y(psi)/t` and `u(x,t=0) = N_0*delta(x)`.

Here D and M are constants, delta(x) is the Dirac delta function and y',y'' indicate the first and second derivative of y with respect to psi. I already tried using sympy, but I got an error saying that the ODE cannot be solved by the factorable group method.
Any suggestions? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Your description of the equations is ambiguous. It isn't even clear what the independent variable in the ODE is. In any case most nonlinear ODEs do not have any analytic solution. Do you have any reason to suppose that this one does?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, the independent variable in the ODE is supposed to be psi. I'm not sure wether it has an anlytic solution, but I've been asked to find one, so I just assumed it would be possible

Comment: You could try to replace `y` by `z=1/y`, it should simplify the equation to some extend or at least give a different view of it. But manual solution is really off-topic here, this would be more a question for math.SE